# Align Labels Verticaly with Custom Radio Button

Tags: html, css, angular

How it looks:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cDWY.png)

I wanted labels with dynamic size so for example 'Very strongly uncomfortable' changes

```
    Very
  Strongly
uncofortable
  [input]
```

Im really not experienced when it comes to css

```html
<div class="w-50 d-flex justify-content-between answer-box">
    <div *ngFor="let label of labels; index as id" class="text-center question-label">
        <span class="mr-2">{{label}}</span>
        <div class="radio">
            <label style="font-size: 2.5em">
                <input type="radio" [value]="id+1" formControlName="value">
                <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i somehow managed to split text, then checkboxes are on different height when there is no label.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**html:**

```
<table class="cBox">
  <tr>
    <td width="10px" >Very Strongly uncofortable</td>
    <td width="20px">Uncertain </td>
    <td width="20px">No Answer </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"/> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"/> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cBox {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. If there is no label it look really bad. I have to add this labels are dynamic. THere is always 8 inputs but number of labels vary